# Recursion with an Array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the concept of recursion. I understand that it is basically a method that calls itself and turns a big problem into a bunch of smaller parts to solve it. What I'm having difficulty with is using recursion with an array. Here is an example in my book:

```
//Precondition: x is an array of n integers
public int recur(int[] x, int n)
{
  int t;

  if(n == 1)
  return x[0];

  else
  {
    t = recur(x, n-1);

    if(x[n-1] > t)
    return x[n-1];

    else 
    return t;
  }
}
```

If anyone has the time, could you explain what this method does and how it works? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: write it on paper and doodle tip wisdom appear

Comment: If it is not clear what the code does, how about writing a small example ;)

Comment: This code looks for maximum value in array

Comment: @Lashane shhhhh! let OP think! is nice to get eureka momments

Comment: Oh, i think I get it. Each call to the recursive method checks to se if the next number in the array is larger than the previous one. And at the end it will return the largest. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took the time to help me understand it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method finds the biggest number among the first `n` elements of an array.

It works by finding the biggest number among the first `n-1` elements; then checking whether the `n`th element is bigger.  The recursion comes in when it finds the biggest number in the first `n-1` elements - it does that by calling itself with `n-1` in place of `n`.

Of course, if `n` is 1, then there's nothing to check - we should just return the first element.  This is the "base case" of the recursion.

Note that when I say the `n`th element, this is actually `x[n-1]`, not `x[n]` because array indexes start from zero.

Answer (score 3):

This function returns the largest integer of an integer array.

Lets see how, Your function recur takes an integer array x and its length n.

If the length of array is 1 then the lone element x[0] is the largest one.

Else we get the largest element from the array starting with x[0] to x[n-2](that is array of length n - 1) and so on, when we get the largest element we keep on sending it as the return value till recursion finishes, finally returning the largest value.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason why we start from n-1 and keep going down? Could you also start with x[0] and keep going up until you get to the value of n?

Comment: you can go from 0 and keep on increasing too, but then you have to let the function know both ends of the array, when we decrease from n to 0, we know that the least index possible to check is 0(that becomes implicit), if you want to increase, you have to explicitly pass on the max limit on the length of the array

Answer (score 0):

In recursion we have what is called base case which is a condition to make the recursion stop. In this situation the base case is `if (n==1)` where the first element of `x[]` is returned.

Let's go to the second part of the recursion. The function is calling itself but decrementing `n`, until it reachs to the base case. Once the base case is returned, the function will compare the first element, now `t`, with the next one `x[n-1]` (where `n` is equal to `2`) and return the greater of both. When one value is returned the function goes to its previous call in the stack.

In other words, to analize recursion you should go through the function calls until the base case is reached and once there, start to go back leaded by the returns or the final execution of the function.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in above answers this method will return largest among the first n values in the array, i would like to show this answer pictorially

Assume array with values
{5, 4, 2, 1, 8, 6, 4, 2, 12, 33}

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
caller |  10  |  9 |  8 |  7  |  6  |  5  |  4  |  3  |  2  |  1  
===================================================================================
  t    |  12  |  8 |  8 |  8  |  8  | 5   |  5  |  5  |  5  |  none 
===================================================================================
return |  33  | 12 |  8 |  8  |  8  |  8  |  5  |  5  |  5  | 5
```

Here caller is the invoker of recursive method. and in the `n = 10`, 33 will be compared with 12 and 33 will be returned to invoker. Hence invoker will received largest value in the array.